# Unable to perform authenticate request using Keycloak from postman

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect, keycloak-connect

I am trying to use an oath2.0 and created a client in Keycloak. All the settings seem to be as per documentation but when I try to use an authorization using postman request, the following error message is showing on a console:

```
Error: Client Certification missing for MTLS HoK Token Binding
```

What I read from different sources this message seems to be part of the OAuth standard where the client should need to use the same certificate when performing OAuth requests. I am using a proxy in front of the Keycloak server and it is using the proper SSL certificate, to overcome this error I try to use the same certificate and the key in postman settings but still I unable to resolve this.
Can someone tell me what I am missing in Keycloak settings OR and how to test OAuth authorization at postman?

Here are the client(oauth) in Keycloak settings:

[image]
[image]

Postman Request for oAuth2.0. Here is the blog link which i used to create postman request for oAuth2.0:
https://medium.com/@bcarunmail/securing-rest-api-using-keycloak-and-spring-oauth2-6ddf3a1efcc2

[Postman request image link](https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*4y3bpCL-R67kZ2hMtyisfA.png)

Comment: Error is saying `Client Certification` = x.509 standard = mutual TLS. So did you send client certificate in the request?

Comment: You need to attach the postman request you are trying with, if you want to get some help.

Comment: @JanGaraj Actually i am very new in this and not getting this idea that how to generate client certificate(MTLS) and what kind of configuration should need to do at Keycloak side to accept this MTLS. Can you please share some ideas about it? WIll be great if you have some online example of creating and using MTLS in Keycloak.

Comment: @XtremeBiker I have updated my question with a postman request which I am using to test oAuth2.0

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Running into same issue.